# Designed an email system. Giving an unfamiliar exception

Tags: delphi, indy

When trying to send an email.. Exception raised :class EIdMTPReplyError with 'Too many login attempts, please try again later.h13sm140491edt.30 - gmstp'

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory.  You tried to login to the SMTP server too many times in a short amount of time.  Do what the error message says and wait awhile before logging in again. And then stop trying to login so often to begin with.  Clearly the server you are connecting to is throttling logins, probably as an anti-spamming measure.

Comment: But this is the first time I logged in which is why i was confused about the exception raised.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact the server thinks you are logging in more times, or sending more emails, than you are allowed to. This is not an Indy issue. You need to take this up with the server admin.

Comment: Okay thank you. Appreciate the feedback alot.